# Changing indexing of an infinte series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, infinite-product

Consider the following manipulations of an infinite series (assume convergence conditions wherever necessary):

> $$ \log\left(\prod_m \frac{1}{1-z^{f(m)}}\right) =
>  \sum_{m}\log\left(\frac{1}{1-z^{f(m)}}\right) = \sum_m
>  \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{z^{if(m)}}{i} \\= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}\sum_{d|n}d\cdot |\{m\in X: f(m)=d\}| $$
>   where $f: X \to \mathbb{N}$ is a well-defined map.

How can the final manipulation of changing the indexing of infinite series make sense? Am I missing something here or there is a simple typo that can be fixed to make the manipulations sensible.

Comment: I would put in an intermediate step with the variable expressed $\frac{z^{n/d}}{n/d}z^d$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician can you please elaborate?

Comment: When you look for the total coefficient of $z^n$ it clearly comes from various $z^{if(m)}$, so it comes from the various $n=d\cdot\frac{n}{d}$ with $d|n$. Write out the first few terms and you'll see where it all comes from.